# How to create a cron job programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cron, crontab

How can I create a cron job in Magento without defining `<run><model></model></run>` in the XML?

I have a lot of jobs that need to be changed programmatically and we couldn't define all of these jobs in the XML as these need to be dynamic.

So far, this insert the job in the magento cron, however, there's no run/model defined:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
                ->load(self::CRON_STRING_PATH, 'path')
                ->setValue($cronExprString)
                ->setPath(self::CRON_STRING_PATH)
                ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code inserts the cron job into `cron_schedule` table:

```
$job_code='my_great_job_code';
/* */
$time = time(); // or time()+60 if you want...
$date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', $time);
/* */
$schedule = Mage::getModel('cron/schedule');
$schedule->setCreatedAt(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', time()));
$schedule->setScheduledAt($date);
$schedule->setStatus(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_PENDING);
$schedule->setJobCode($job_code);
$schedule->save();
```

Comment: And what does it execute? Nothing it seems.

Comment: This code insert line into cron_schedule table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$timecreated   = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
$timescheduled = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", mktime(date("H"), date("i")+ 5, date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
$jobCode = 'job_id';

try {
    $schedule = Mage::getModel('cron/schedule');
     $schedule->setJobCode($jobCode)
        ->setCreatedAt($timecreated)
        ->setScheduledAt($timescheduled)
        ->setStatus(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_PENDING)
        ->save();
   } catch (Exception $e) {
     throw new Exception(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Unable to save Cron expression'));
   }
```

Also check [More Details...](https://www.ayasoftware.com/how-create-cron-jobs-dynamically-magento)

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you also need a run model defined otherwise Magento just skips the entry.
I am just having the same problem, here is what you need additionaly to the one you already have.

```
Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
        ->load('crontab/jobs/JOBNAME/run/model', 'path')
        ->setValue('classhandle/class_name::run')
        ->setPath('crontab/jobs/JOBNAME/run/model')
        ->save();
```

Magento actually does something like this if you check class **Mage_Backup_Model_Config_Backend_Cron**.